# Python nested dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures

I made a code to generate json. The code is :

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(dict)

    with open(res_file, 'w') as f:
        for i, box in enumerate(boxes):


            a=np.split(poly,4)

            d[i][str(0)] = str(a[0])
            d[i][str(1)] = str(a[1])
            d[i][str(2)] = str(a[2])
            d[i][str(3)] = str(a[3])

            y = json.dumps(d)
            print(y)
```

Its output is

> {"0": {"0": "[429  44]", "1": "[436  44]", "2": "[436  56]", "3":
>   "[429  56]"}, "1": {"0": "[345  41]", "1": "[431  44]", "2": "[430 
>   69]", "3": "[344  66]"}, "2": {"0": "[453  42]", "1": "[554  42]",
>   "2": "[554  68]", "3": "[453  68]"}, "3": {"0": "[654  45]", "1":
>   "[710  45]", "2": "[710  76]", "3": "[654  76]"}, "4": {"0": "[436 
>   48]", "1": "[449  48]", "2": "[449  66]", "3": "[436  66]"}, "5":
>   {"0": "[153  58]", "1": "[287  61]", "2": "[286  97]", "3": "[152 
>   93]"}, "6": {"0": "[345  70]", "1": "[438  70]", "2": "[438  94]",
>   "3": "[345  94]"}, "7": {"0": "[442  69]", "1": "[477  69]", "2":
>   "[477  94]", "3": "[442  94]"}, "8": {"0": "[481  69]", "1": "[602 
>   69]", "2": "[602  94]", "3": "[481  94]"}, "9": {"0": "[638  76]",
>   "1": "[724  76]", "2": "[724  94]", "3": "[638  94]"}, "10": {"0":
>   "[293 117]", "1": "[313 117]", "2": "[313 132]", "3": "[293 132]"},
>   "11": {"0": "[316 117]", "1": "[361 117]", "2": "[361 132]", "3":
>   "[316 132]"}

I want to do this: If all the boxes (in above example 11 boxes) have successfully executed running then append the result with:

```
"Message":"success",
"Status":1,
```

My final output json should look like:

```
{ 
    "Status":1,
    "Message":"success",
    "Result":{ 
        "1":{ 
            "1":"[431,44]",
            "0":"[345,41]",
            "3":"[344,66]",
            "2":"[430,69]"
        },
        "0":{ 
            "1":"[436,44]",
            "0":"[429,44]",
            "3":"[429,56]",
            "2":"[436,56]"
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create one more dict with required fields:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(dict)

with open(res_file, 'w') as f:
    for i, box in enumerate(boxes):
        poly = np.array(box).astype(np.int32).reshape((-1))
        a = np.split(poly, 4)
        for j in range(4):
            d[i][str(j)] = str(a[j])

result = {
    'Status': int(bool(d)),  # 0 - dict empty, 1 - dict not empty
    'Message': 'success' if d else 'fail',  # ('fail', 'success')[int(bool(d))]
    'Result': d
}
```

If you need to print this dict indented, you can use `json.dumps()`:

```
import json

print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

Comment: Hi Olvin, one question what if there are no boxes, this code will still print 'success'. It should return fail in this case

Answer (score 0):

I am not replicating your entire code.Assuming that your above code works fine to return the data, use the code below your nested dict.

Please have a look at the below code.

```
#To dump the json output you will require the json package, import it using
import json

#this is the data which you have dumped in your question, assuming that your above code generates this data
data = {'0': {'0': '[429 44]', '1': '[436 44]', '2': '[436 56]', '3': '[429 56]'}, '1': {'0': '[345 41]', '1': '[431 44]', '2': '[430 69]', '3': '[344 66]'}, '2': {'0': '[453 42]', '1': '[554 42]', '2': '[554 68]', '3': '[453 68]'}, '3': {'0': '[654 45]', '1': '[710 45]', '2': '[710 76]', '3': '[654 76]'}, '4': {'0': '[436 48]', '1': '[449 48]', '2': '[449 66]', '3': '[436 66]'}, '5': {'0': '[153 58]', '1': '[287 61]', '2': '[286 97]', '3': '[152 93]'}, '6': {'0': '[345 70]', '1': '[438 70]', '2': '[438 94]', '3': '[345 94]'}, '7': {'0': '[442 69]', '1': '[477 69]', '2': '[477 94]', '3': '[442 94]'}, '8': {'0': '[481 69]', '1': '[602 69]', '2': '[602 94]', '3': '[481 94]'}, '9': {'0': '[638 76]', '1': '[724 76]', '2': '[724 94]', '3': '[638 94]'}, '10': {'0': '[293 117]', '1': '[313 117]', '2': '[313 132]', '3': '[293 132]'}, '11': {'0': '[316 117]', '1': '[361 117]', '2': '[361 132]', '3': '[316 132]'}}

final_data = {
    "Status": 1 if data else 0,
    "Message": "success" if data else "failed",
    "Result": data
}
```

Use the json package to dump the data as json

```
d = json.dumps(final_data,indent=4)

print(d)
```

Hope this helps

Thanks

Comment: It's weird to create empty `dict` and use `update()` in next expression to fill it.

Comment: Maybe you are right @OlvinRoght. You can just skip that step and directly assign the value to a new variable final_data = {"key": "value"}

Comment: yup @Shabbir thats more of a c,c++ style coding. There is no such thing as "variable declaration" or "variable initialization" in Python.

Comment: You can shorten `if len(data) > 0` to `if data`